# Передать значения списков в функцию python

Tags: python

Почти уверен, что ответ должен быть уже на форуме, но не нашёл.

Имеется два списка, скажем :

```
names = ['Andrey','Roman','Kirill','Dmitrii',]
lastnames = ['Ostapov','Bolshov','Mihailov','Romanov',]
```

мне необходимо перебрать списки и передать их значения в функцию, например такую:

```
def fullnames(name,lastname):
    fullname = {name:lastname,}
    return fullname
```

как это правильно сделать?
был вариант перебора через for, но если списки вложенные по типу

```
for name in names:
    for lastname in lastnames:
```

то, соответственно, я получаю одно имя и все фамилии, что не верно

есть рабочий вариант с

```
for i in range(len(names)):
    print(fulnames(names[i], lastnames[i]))
```

Но я хочу найти другой способ, чтобы не привязываться к длине одного списка.
Так-же, если подскажете как переделать функцию, чтобы это был один словарь, а не несколько разных, буду крайне благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `zip`:

```
def fullname(name, lastname):
    return name + ' ' + lastname

for name, lastname in zip(names, lastnames):
    print(fulname(name, lastname))
```

Однако, если списки разного размера, то результат будет тот же, что и:

```
for i in range(min(len(names), len(lastnames))):
    print(fullname(names[i], lastnames[i]))
```